# Create splash screen on android with GIF is freeze when start main activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create **SplashScreenActivity** and show **WebView** with **GIF** file before call:

```
StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity))
```

I found that the animation was stopped when **StartActivity** is called.

I also try to use **AnimationDrawable** to play the animation as a frame instead. But the result was the same: The animation will be stopped when **StartActivity** is called.

I think these happened because **UIThread** is blocked when call **StartActivity**.

Is there anyway to use animation as splash screen that will not be blocked while **MainActivity** is call to start `Xamarin`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add some sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways , the easiest way to set gif in your splash screen is that ,just create custom views and load .gif image like [this](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.in/2014/04/animated-gif-imageview-library-for.html)

Comment: Would a VideoView work better? Any issues on using a Video instead of the gif image?

Comment: @AndersonOki : that is depends on app requirement.if you want to play video on splash screen then you should use video view or if you want just .gif image in splash screen then make one view that loads .gif image efficiently as mention in above link.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Task.Delay(2000).Wait();` in SplashScreenActivity before you call start main activity for duration you want the animation to play